# Convert pdf information into excel

Tags: html, excel, vba, pdf, converters

for my master thesis I need the information of a advertising brochure in an excel-sheet with 5 rows.
Productname/NormalPrice/DiscountPrice/Size/Unit

I tried a couple of converting tools like PDFTables or PDFelement6Pro but the results are not useful.

below is an link to the brochure.

https://www.netto-online.de/media/handzettel/flipbook/2018-19-5ea4be9e321e3ad2c095e54b938d1466/coss/hz19_cosf.pdf

maybe subody can help.

thank you

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note, that this is not a free code-writing service. Yet, we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) writing their own code. Please read the help topics on [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and earn a badge while doing so. Afterwards, please update your question with the VBA code you have written thus far in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve. We will be here waiting for you. Ready to assist and help you finalize *your code*.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, the tools you mentioned should work fine to parse data from a PDF to Excel.  However, those tools are designed to import data from tables, in a PDF, to Excel.  I didn't see any tables in the URL you provided.  You can try to save the PDF as a text file and import the text into Excel.  That's usually a nice work-around.  However, a second time, I dind't see much, if any, text in that file.  It looks like it is all images.  As far as I know, you can't save an image as text.